# After using cassandra 3.4 node in not reachable

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

I have installed cassandra 3.4`on machine`192.168.1.3` and trying to acces from othet machine i am getting

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /192.168.1.3:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/192.168.1.3] Cannot connect))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:231)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:77)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1414)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:162)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:333)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:308)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:250)
```

Here is my connection code

```
    cluster = Cluster.builder()
    .addContactPoints(nodes)
    .withRetryPolicy(DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
    .withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(100L))
    .build();
    session = cluster.connect();
```

I am able to ping `192.168.1.3` machine. and cassandra is running. it was working nice before i started using cassandra 3.4.i am using datastax cassandra-driver-core3.0.0 driver

Comment: Basic troubleshooting steps include logging into that server ensuring the process is really running, checking server logs for errors, and trying to connect from that server. Once you've done all three of those things, you'd want to try telnetting from one machine to 19.2168.1.3:9042 - if that works, then cassandra is available, and you likely have a config issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use SocketOption . In this you have to give time to connection must equal or more then you put Cassandra.conf file .